# Identifying Colours from a Photograph - Android

Tags: java, android

Given a photograph, is there a way to identify the colour of each pixel?

I'm hoping to create an Android app for a school project, and I wish to be able to determine the colours of specific area's within a photograph on the phone.  Is it possible to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [getPixel function from Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html)

(You would need to get it in bitmap format, and that would mean using some memory so mind that!)

Comment: Thanks - I have only just (yesterday) started learning Android development, so I will bear the memory part in mind.  Would converting a photo into a bitmap be highly memory intensive?

Comment: Depends, but reading and not compressing a picture in memory as a bitmap could have you gettin near that feared 16mb heapspace limit. Just keep it in mind ;)